# flutter barcode scanner android issue

Tags: flutter, permissions, camera

I am new to flutter, I have created a barcode reader app for ios and android. I use the flutter_barcode_scanner plugin: 2.0.0 or any, while on ios I have no problem when I open the camera, with android after passing the permissions and having managed them correctly I get a black screen.
I use the brand new flutter sdk 2.11 and I don't understand why it can't work in android, although I have seen many tutorials and followed step by step, does anyone have any idea what this might depend on?

This is the log when i try to open camera

W/m.falco.lettur(18788): Accessing hidden method
Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getOpticalInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)

W/m.falco.lettur(18788): Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking

W/m.falco.lettur(18788): Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)

W/m.falco.lettur(18788): Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking)

the problem is this:
**if i open camera from mainPageNavigator all is ok,while instead open from the other page i have black screen,only in android.**

Comment: I think we need more info. Do you see anything in the logs? Also try to watch logcat in Android Studio to see if there are logs at that moment that you are not shown in Flutter console.

Comment: i add comment on my post

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the permission that you are passing in androidmanifest.xml

you need to pass these permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
```

Comment: i have the first two internet and camera, and i try to add the other 3,but never change

Comment: You are testing app on android app or emulator

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/qrscan try to use this library its working for me

Comment: i tested up both android device and emulator,i think the problem is in plugin that was mase on java code ,while flutter work in kotlin,maybe.

Answer (score 0):

**Access Camera Permission**

**path:** `android/app/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <application
```

Comment: i have this permission

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this in your android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml before < application>  ?

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />`

Comment: i try now but never change,thanks

Comment: Does it showing any error? Also which brand phone you are using for testing?

Comment: I edit post with new logcat on device samsung and 11